# Adding Text To System Error Output?

Tags: error, error-messages, debugging

I'm writing triggers for two highly interdependent objects, and they kind of need to circle around passing the insert/update ball back and forth to each other to the extent allowable because there are so many other active vendor-provided triggers that could change data anywhere in the execution context, and I'm being asked to write triggers that can handle it gracefully.

I'm trying to figure out code to handle the "gracefully pass the ball without raising errors or causing infinite loops" requirement of this project, and as I try random things, I keep getting various errors that aren't very helpful (e.g. an error comes up inside a protected vendor trigger, so no proper stack trace).

I'd like to add my own "stack traces" by peppering my code with things along the lines of `System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,'Got to ContactTriggerHandler, line 34; Contact.LastName is currently '+c.LastName');` so I can watch a sort of "stack trace" over *my* code.

The only problem is that our debug logs, even at the tightest levels of output, get so cluttered with crap from other vendors' inefficient work that they size out before I even get to my DEBUG statements.

When my code doesn't error out and I just want to watch where I am, I add messages to a static list in a Util class and, at the last minute, somewhere in my test class, just do a `System.assert(FALSE, printUtilLog());` so I can query ApexTestResult for a nice, readable "stack trace" of things I care about.

However, this is a situation where **I'm not in control of raising the error** -- but I'd love to force whatever error **does** come up to include, in its message/stacktrace, any text I've "set aside" along the way.

**Is there a command that basically says, "Don't let this command *cause* an error, but if an error comes up down the road, append this text to that error's normal explanatory messages?"**

Comment: I don't think I can really answer your question, but have you taken a look at [Apex checkpoints](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm&type=5)?

Comment: Thanks, but looking to be able to log every time a line of code was passed over, not just the first (I can see the yes/no from the blue/red highlighting of code coverage).  It's more like ... I know what my data is; if I watch it make its way through the code, I can figure out at what point in its "lifecycle" the crash is REALLY happening.  Basically like one would do with a System.Debug, only I'm looking for something resistant to the log clutter.

Comment: Don't think there is a general way to append to an error.  Outputting debug info at `LoggingLevel.ERROR` and setting the Apex Code level to "Error" usually works to fit in the 2M (unless the vendors are using the same trick). Is that what you are doing? Salesforce support will up the log file size but only to about 10M. You might also consider using the Apex debugger now its generally available.